# Mongoose Init Arrays with empty array instead of undefined

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After some debugging, I came up with this code:

```
var trackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  playedAtTimestamps: Array
});

trackSchema.post('init', function(track) {
  track.playedAtTimestamps = track.playedAtTimestamps || [];
});
```

So that anywhere else in the code, I know `track.playedAtTimestamps` is an `Array`. But I have the feeling my post-init callback is redundant to my Schema definition.

Is there a better practice? Should we somehow modify Mongoose's behavior?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need the post init middleware, `playedAtTimestamps` will already be an empty array by default. Are you seeing something else?

Comment: Yes, I get `track.playedAtTimestamps` set to `undefined`, which raises an error while doing `track.playedAtTimestamps.push(newTimestamp)`...

Comment: Can you update your question with the code to reproduce this? It's working when I try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha :facepalm

I was doing

```
  Track.findOne({})
  .select('title') // Here is the mistake, I was not fetching playedAtTimestamps
  .exec(function(err, track){
    console.log(track);
    track.incCounterSync((new Date()).getTime()); // Here is the error
    track.save(function(err, track){
      console.log(track);
    });
  });
```